# R plot,why is introducing of axis limits creating havoc?

Tags: r, plot

My code

```
library(Hmisc)

r1 <- read.table("mt7.1r1.rp", header = FALSE) 
r2 <- read.table("mt7.1r2.rp", header = FALSE) 
r3 <- read.table("mt7.2r1.rp", header = FALSE) 
r4 <- read.table("mt7.2r2.rp", header = FALSE)

p1=r1[1]
per1=log10(p1)
p2=r2[1]
per2=log10(p2)
p3=r3[1]
per3=log10(p3)
p4=r4[1]
per4=log10(p4)

m1=nrow(per1)
m2=nrow(per2)
m3=nrow(per3)
m4=nrow(per4)

xmin <- floor( min(per1,per2,per3,per4))
xmax <- ceiling( max(per1,per2,per3,per4))

lxmax=10^(xmax)
lxmin=10^(xmin)

rhoaxy = r2[3]
phaxy = r2[5]

rhoayx = r3[3]
phayx = r3[5]

rhoaxx = r1[3]
phaxx = r1[5]

rhoayy = r4[3]
phayy = r4[5]


per2=unname(per2)
per2=unlist(per2)
per3=unname(per3)
per3=unlist(per3)

rhoaxy=unname(rhoaxy)
rhoaxy=unlist(rhoaxy)
rhoaxy=log10(rhoaxy)
rhoayx=unname(rhoayx)
rhoayx=unlist(rhoayx)
rhoayx=log10(rhoayx)

ymin1=floor(min(rhoaxy)-1)
ymax1=ceiling(max(rhoaxy)+1)
ymin2=floor(min(rhoayx)-1)
ymax2=ceiling(max(rhoayx)+1)
ymin=min(ymin1,ymin2)
ymax=max(ymax1,ymax2)

png("withlim.png")

plot(per2,rhoaxy, col='red', xlab='Per (s)', ylab = 'Rho-xy/yx',ylim=c(ymin, ymax))
par(new=TRUE)
plot(per3,rhoayx, col='green', xaxt='n', xlab= NA, yaxt = 'n', ylab = NA)

dev.off()
```

The image I got 
[image]

If I delete ylim
[image]

My question is,why are the axis limits changing the image content?The values from the second image correspond to proper data values.The first image is with values that do not represent rhoaxy and rhoayx.

Comment: @ZheyuanLi Set a common ylim before plot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is difficult to test without the data, but my guess is that, on the second plot, the Y axis is not the same, although the Y axis is not plot.

So you've got the superposition of 2 plot, with a different Y axis.
If you want the same ylim on both plot, add `ylim=c(ymin, ymax)` on the second plot also.

If it does not work, please provide data example, so we can test.